# PowerShell pipeline Get-Content to split and then select expression

Tags: powershell, pipeline

i have a file and i want split selective lines and take selective cells.

this work:

```
Get-Content F:\dat | ? {$_  -like "1,*"} | % {$_.Split(',')}
```

but I can not continue to concatenate a select some items:

```
Get-Content F:\dat | ? {$_  -like "1,*"} | % {$_.Split(',')} | Select -Property  @{name="Name"; expression = {$_[0]}}, @{name="Value"; expression = {$_[5]}}
```

i recive unexepted result, suce as the file like this:

> 1,"123",456,"bla bla bla",0,569.2

the result exepted:

```
Name  Value  
1     569.2
```

1     569.2

the result done:

```
Name Value  
---- ----   
  1        
  "        
  4        
  "  b      
  0        
  5
```

Comment: I think you have a typo? `%` (`ForEach-Object`) doesn't have a `-Property` member.

Comment: `% {$_.Split(',')}` -> `% {,$_.Split(',')}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `ConvertFrom-Csv` instead:

```powershell
Get-Content F:\dat|
Where-Object {$_ -like "1,*"}|
ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Name,Ignore1,Ignore2,Ignore3,Ignore4,Value|
Select-Object Name,Value
```

Comment: you right but actualy i cant becouse only the lines wich start with 1 is comma sperated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is were it all breaks down:

```
| % {$_.Split(',')} |
```

The next command in your pipeline will just receive an enumerable stream of individual strings (the results of the split operation), not arrays of strings.

Thus, the `$_[0]` operation is parsed as "Take the first [char] from this string", which is why you see the strange output you get.

Wait until you actually calculate the properties before splitting the string:

```
Get-Content F:\dat | ? {$_  -like "1,*"} | Select -Property  @{name="Name"; expression = {$_.Split(',')[0]}}, @{name="Value"; expression = {$_.Split(',')[5]}}
```

Comment: thank' but i understand half. I can not move an object to the pipeline an array on an individual item? It bothers me that your solution taken by the division again and again. Really it is about 15 times and it is multiplied hundreds of rows.